# a problem may use L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: analysis

[image]

I cannot get the $f'(0)$ by using L'Hôpital's rule, because it appears recurrence item. Can you help me?

Comment: What does "it appears recurrence item" even mean?

Comment: You cannot talk about $f'(0)$ without showing differentiability. You have to construct the difference quotient explicitly, and use obvious bounds on $\sin$ to compute it. That way, L' Hopital is avoided and you get the answer, which should be $0$ (the left sided differential quotient is $0$),

Comment: Thank you, your help is very useful! Initially I differentiate $\sin{(\frac{1}{x^3})}$ but the result is too complex to slove. After bounding on $\sin$, I can get the result easily!

Comment: @Gatsby I tried Taylor series. It comes in handy

Comment: @ZackNi I tried your method, but it may appear some $x^{-n}$ due to $\sin{(\frac{1}{x^3})}$. How to deal with it?

Comment: @Gatsby $-(2x + \frac{x^5}{3} + \frac{x^9}{60} + O(x^{13})) <\sin (\frac{1}{x^3}) (2x + \frac{x^5}{3} + \frac{x^9}{60} + O(x^{13})) < (2x + \frac{x^5}{3} + \frac{x^9}{60} + O(x^{13})) $ Then use sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the derivative, a function $f$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}$$

exists.  In this case, $f(0)$ is *defined* to be $0$, so the question of differentiability boils down to examining

$$\lim_{x\to0}{(e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2})\sin({1\over x^3})\over x}$$

Note first that

$$\left|{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}\over x}\sin\left({1\over x^3}\right) \right|\le \left|{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}\over x} \right|\quad\text{for }x\not=0$$

since $|\sin\theta|\le1$ for all $\theta$.  L'Hopital shows

$$\lim_{x\to0}{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}\over x}=\lim_{x\to0}{2xe^{x^2}-(-2x)e^{-x^2}\over 1}=\lim_{x\to0}2x(e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2})=0$$

Therefore, by the Squeeze Theorem, the limit with the sine function also tends to $0$.  I.e., we have

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{(e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2})\sin({1\over x^3})\over x}=0$$

Remark:  If $f(0)$ had been defined to be anything other than $0$, $f$ would *not* be differentiable at $0$ for the simple reason that $f$ would not be *continuous* at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of f at $0$ can be calculated:

$$ f'(0) = \lim_{ x \to 0 } \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \frac{({e}^{{x}^{2}} - {e}^{{-x}^{2}} )\sin (\frac{1}{x^3})}{x}$$

Then try to use L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor series to see the derivative.

Comment: Showing that two expressions are identical does not prove that the derivative (i.e., the limit) exists.  For example, you would have gotten identical expressions if the function for $x\not=0$ had simply been $f(x)=\sin({1\over x^3})$.

Comment: I'm not sure your point in including (1). (2) is enough, and (1) can be misleading, because that limit can exist when there is not derivative. For example, if $f(x)=|x|$, then $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2x} = 0$, but $f$ is not differentiable

Answer (score 0):

For $x\ne 0$ we have $|\sin \frac {1}{x^3}|\leq 1.$ We have $e^x=1+x +O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$. So $e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}=2x^2 +O(x^4)$ as $x\to 0.$ So for $x\ne 0$ we have $$|\frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}|=|\frac {f(x)}{x}|\leq  |\frac {e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{x}|=|\frac {2x^2+O(x^4)}{x}|=$$ $$=|2x+O(x^3)|.$$ So $f'(0)=0 .$